# Linq Take changing the query result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Right now I'm using

```
db.Products.Skip(0).Take(10).ToList();
```

But it changes the result of my set.

For example:

```
//product.Name = Ball    
var product = db.Products.ToList()[5];

//product.Name = Ball    
var product = db.Products.Skip(0).ToList()[5];

//product.Name = Sleigh (it skips the "Ball" product)
var product = db.Products.Take(10).ToList()[5];
```

Is there a reason for why that's happening?

I'm using

```
Skip(0)
```

because I'm on the first page of my application.

According to my dataset, it should return "Ball" as the 5° product of my set.

If I try

```
db.Products.ToList().Take(10).ToList();
```

it works just fine.

edit: I'm sorry for my incomplete question, didn't think it was necessary to say but I'm ordering my list using:

```
produtosQuery = produtosQuery
                    .OrderByDescending(pro => pro.Likes.Where(like =>
                        like.UsuarioId == usuarioId &&
                        like.IsAtivo == true).Count())
                    .ThenByDescending(pro => pro.Compras.Count)
                    .ThenByDescending(pro => pro.Likes.Count(like => like.IsAtivo));
```

Comment: You need to add an ordering to get it in the way you want it. `var product = db.Products.OrderBy(pro => pro.Name).Take(10).ToList();` something along those lines with some property in that class.

Comment: Currently you're not specifying an ordering - if this is a database table, that probably means the order is arbitrary. "The first ten items" would be non-deterministic. Try specifying an appropriate ordering in all cases, and I suspect the problem will go away.

Comment: What type database are you using?  some databases like SQL Server are multi-threaded and do not return data in the same order as stored.  The order is random.  You need to use an OrderBy to guarantee the order of the results.

Comment: Add an intermediate variable that refers to the IEnumerable returned from the LINQ statement. Then call `ToList` on that variable. If you step through your code in the debugger, then that intermediate will contain a property that holds the SQL that was executed (break after the ToList is called). The SQL statements may tell you more.

Comment: You are returning in this order index 10, 5, 5, 15

Answer (score 5):

Note that Product is not an ordered list and it is *not* guaranteed that items will always be in the same order.

To make sure of that you need to order it first.

```
db.Products.OrderBy(item => item.someProperty).Take(10).ToList();
```

Also you first `.ToList()` is extra.

```
db.Products.ToList().Take(10).ToList();
           ^^^^^^^^^  //don't need this one here
```